# Python: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Tags: python

I am working with an exchange for cryptocurrency which requires an encoding of the secret API key to gain access to private API calls. I have copied and pasted their Python code to begin executing my calls with it, but I receive this error every time I make a request.

```
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

I know what this means; I am a programmer. I can not find the root of the problem in the code I have received from the exchange, as I have not worked with hmac, hashlib, or base64. I have replaced all instances of the name of the exchange with the word "exchange" in the following code. No API keys are shown.

```
exchangeconfig = Exchange('key', 'secret')

base = 'https://exchange.com/'
def post_request(key, secret, path, data):
    hmac_obj = hmac.new(secret, path + chr(0) + data, hashlib.sha512)
    hmac_sign = base64.b64encode(hmac_obj.digest())
    header = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'User-Agent': 'exchangev2 based client',
        'Rest-Key': key,
        'Rest-Sign': hmac_sign,
    }
    proxy = ProxyHandler({'http': '127.0.0.1:8888'})
    opener = build_opener(proxy)
    install_opener(opener)
    request = Request(base + path, data, header)
    response = urlopen(request, data)
    return json.load(response)
def gen_tonce():
    return str(int(time.time() * 1e6))
class Exchange:
    def __init__(self, key, secret):
        self.key = key
        self.secret = base64.b64decode(secret)
    def request(self, path, params={}):
        params = dict(params)
        params['tonce'] = gen_tonce()
        # data = urllib.urlencode(params)
        data = json.dumps(params)
        result = post_request(self.key, self.secret, path, data)
        if result['result'] == 'success':
            return result['data']
        else:
            raise Exception(result['result'])

exchangeconfig.request("api/3/account")
```

Please help me figure this out. 
By the way: It seems to have a problem with this line in particular:

```
hmac_obj = hmac.new(secret, path + chr(0) + data, hashlib.sha512)
```

Thanks.

UPDATE: Fixed that error. Now onto this one:

```
TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.
```

Answer (score 0):

These hash libraries deal with bytes objects, so you should encode your strings to bytes first (assuming the decoding end uses UTF-8):

```
hmac_obj = hmac.new(secret, path.encode('utf-8') + b'\0' + data.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha512)
```

Comment: Given this is a networked program, you shouldn't rely on the default locale encoding; pass `'utf-8'` (or some other agreed upon encoding) as the argument to `encode` explicitly. Also, `chr(0)` should be changed to `b'\0'` or the concatenation will fail.

Comment: I've updated my code. New error: TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.

Comment: @JoshMalinkovich You should encode `data` when making a request as well:  `request = Request(base + path, data.encode('utf-8'), header)`. By the way the `data` in the line that follows is redundant: `response = urlopen(request)`

Comment: You should simply accept this answer and post a new question about the new problem. Linking back to this question would be good form, as would reducing the problem statement to a [mcve].